How to concat two arrays in mongoose and retain unique values
I have two collections

Roles

Users -> which has the reference to roles as array


User schema
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    id: { type: String }, 
    username: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    phone: { type: String, required: false, unique:true }, 
    email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    password: { type: String, required: true },
    roles: [
        { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true, ref:'Role' } 
    ],
    otp: {
        required: false,
        type:String
    }
});


module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

I want to update roles so below is my code
const rolesArr = get(validated, 'value.roles'); // ['super-administrator', 'administrator']

const usernameArr = get(validated, 'value.users'); // ['user-1', 'user-2']

const roles = await Role.find({slug:{$in:rolesArr}}); //  roles collection array matching role slug

const set = {      
    $push: {         // pushes into the existing array
        roles: roles
    }
}

const users = await User.updateMany({username: {$in: usernameArr}}, set);

What happens is the user-1 gets the administrator more than once, because it just pushes the passed role object.

Expected: If the administrator role exists, then do not add to the array.
I tried to follow link , but could not succeed in formatting the update condition

I achieved the task with below code
roles.forEach(async role => {
    const query = {$and:[{username:{$in:usernameArr}},{roles: {$nin:role}}]};
    const set = {$push:{roles:role}}
    const user = await User.updateMany(query, set);
})

Explantation:
Loop through the roles. Find users with roles not in role. Push the role
How to remove from an array
roles.forEach(async role => {
    const query = {$and:[{username:{$in:usernameArr}},{roles: {$in:role}}]};
    const set = {$pull:{roles:{$in:[role]}}}
    const user = await User.updateMany(query, set);
})

Use pull to remove from the array.
Find users with roles and remove the specified role
